# JUnit test struts2 action

Tags: junit, struts2

I am using Struts 2.0 in my application. I want to test my struts action clasess with Junit testing. Which jar file should I use for this. Can i use Struts test? Currently, I was trying to use struts Junit plugin but it always show exception for Spring framework `NoClassDefFoundError`, but I am not using Spring in my project. What should I do?.

I am getting this error, when I am extending `StrutsTestCase`.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader


java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/mock/web/MockServletContext
```

Comment: Just add required libs. See dependencies for S2 junit plugin: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/struts/struts2-junit-plugin/2.3.20/struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.20.pom.

Comment: It works for me. i mean the error has gone.


Apart from my appln libraries i have included below jars into my calssspath and i am able to run Junit testcase for my Struts2 Actions.

1. portlet-2.0
2. spring-core-2.5.5
3. spring-test
3. struts2-junit-plugin-2.3.8

Comment: Thanks You all for your help! appreciate it.

Comment: @kani Can you post the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have all required libs on the classpath. Inspect the classpath of your program to see where it actually points.

From their docs:

"In order to run the tests, you must have the following libraries in your CLASSPATH:

junit.jar
servlet.jar
struts.jar
commons-digester.jar
commons-collections.jar
commons-logging.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
jaxp.jar
crimson.jar
strutstest.jar"

It is not obvious why the Spring classes would be required here.

Try running their examples to see if you get the same error.

Comment: Thanks amahfouz for your quick response.

Comment: i have all the above required library in my classpath but still facing the same problem. i dont know why it requires spring clasess.

Comment: Did you try to run their examples?

Comment: Hmmm. Well, maybe their documentation is out of date and you actually need to add those libs to the classpath. Perhaps newer versions of the libs they require do need Spring to be included. Please try including the required Spring libs and see what happens.

Comment: There is a README that is included in the download inside the "examples" folder.

Comment: Thanks You all for your help! appreciate it.